# Deleting head on linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to c and trying to do my Homework. I need to create and insert data into linked list and then print it and delete one of the node inside the list.

```cpp
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>



    typedef struct node{
        int data;
        struct node * next;
    }node;


    void printlist(node *head);
    void dele(int del,node * head);
    node * create(int n);



    int main(){
        int n=0,del;
        node * head=NULL;
        printf("Enter Number of Data: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        head=create(n);
        printf("Data in linked list are : ");
        printlist(head);
        printf("\nEnter Data yout want to delete : ");
        scanf("%d",&del);
        dele(del,head);
        printf("Data remained in linked list are : ");
        printlist(head);
        return 0;
    }

    node * create (int n){
        int i=0;
        node * head = NULL;
        node * temp = NULL;
        node * p = NULL;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            printf("Enter Data%d : ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
            temp->next=NULL;

            if(head==NULL){
                head= temp;
            }
            else{
                p = head;
                while(p->next != NULL){
                    p=p->next;

                }
                p->next=temp;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }

    void printlist(node * head){
        node *n=head;
        while(n!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",n-> data);
        n=n->next;
        }
    }
    void dele(int del,node * head){
        int found = 0, position = 0, i;
      struct node *temp = head;
      struct node *prev = NULL;

      while(temp != NULL)
      {

        if(temp->data == del )
        {
            if(prev == NULL){ /*If the node is the head*/
                head = head->next;
                delete temp;
                return ;
            }else{
                prev->next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return ;
            }
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
      }


    }
```

Everything is ok but there is a problem when I'm trying to delete the first node, the random number start showing up.

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Li29.jpg)
- [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAJUO.jpg)

but when I try to delete other node it's show the result perfectly.
Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the deleting scenario, I am not familiar with **delete tmp**. But I'd suggest you freeing the memory by free(temp) after head point to the next. Also here:

```
head = head-> next
```

You must consider that the next may be NULL sometimes. Leading you to a **segmentation fault**.

==============================================

Edit:

I've analyzed and found the possible solution.

Consider changing: `void dele(int del,node ** head);`
to
`void dele(int del,node ** head);`, and call the function passing the memory address by using the address of operator & before head in the dele call, thus you will be deleting the node from the head itself, and not the reference only (that lead you to the 0):
`dele(del,&head);`.

Thus you will be passing the address, of the head to the function, that will receive a pointer to a pointer. Remember to change the parameter in the function implementation itself also.

After that, the reference of the head to temp in your delete function must be passed as follow, so temp may point to the head pointer. Then, you can make the head point to the next element of temp, that stores the head pointer.

```
struct node *temp = *head;


if(prev == NULL){ /*If the node is the head*/
   *head = temp->next;
   free(temp);
   return ;
}
```

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-pointer-pointer-pointer-c/) may lead you to some understanding about pointer to point in C.

Comment: What you describe will not lead to a segmentation fault. This line will be executed when the first node is to be deleted, which guarantees that `head` in not null. If `head->next` is null, the new head is now null, meaning that the list is now empty. That's absolutely valid.

Comment: You're right. I also saw that he is printing non NULL values. I'm checking the behavior atm.

Comment: @Kennet Emerson, one cool thing of stackoverflow, is that you can edit your own answer. This is not an issue, and if you want to be clear that it was not your original answer, you can highlight it like with "EDIT" for instance. It is perfectly fine, even if this is because someone else mentioned it to you. What matter is that readers read correct things. You can even edit your comments !

Comment: Hey, @Heyji . I just got here :) And I was trying to understand what he did, and just edit with the solution. Also I referenced a link where he can also get deep in the understanding of pointer to point, that lead to the solution. Also, thank you very much for the advice =)

Comment: @Kennet Emerson: that's much better, congrat's. Also you will see that edit's history is kept, so at the end, if your answer is completly different, you don't need to keep your old words (it is archived). Plus you can also vote other's comment if you fill it is helpful.

Comment: Nice, thanks again for the advice. @Heyji That's my first contribution, and I'll keep that in mind for the future =).

Answer (score 1):

You must change the signature of `dele` this way :

```
void dele(int del, node ** head)
```

Then you must adjust the content accordingly, this lines are especially important for your issue :

```
if (prev == NULL){ /* If the node is the head */
    
    if (head) *head = (*head)->next;
}
```

Finally you call `dele` by passing a pointer to `head` :

```
dele(del, &head);
```

This way the new `head` will be visible outside the function (which it is not in your current codes).